# 5x5 matrix multiplication in C

Tags: c, matrix

I am stuck on this problem in my homework. I've made it this far and am sure the problem is in my three for loops. The question directly says to use 3 for loops so I know this is probably just a logic error.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void matMult(int A[][5],int B[][5],int C[][5]);
int printMat_5x5(int A[5][5]);

int main() {

 int A[5][5] = {{1,2,3,4,6},
       {6,1,5,3,8},
       {2,6,4,9,9},
       {1,3,8,3,4},
       {5,7,8,2,5}};

 int B[5][5] = {{3,5,0,8,7},
       {2,2,4,8,3},
       {0,2,5,1,2},
       {1,4,0,5,1},
       {3,4,8,2,3}};

 int C[5][5] = {0};

 matMult(A,B,C);

 printMat_5x5(A);
 printf("\n");

 printMat_5x5(B);
 printf("\n");

 printMat_5x5(C);

 return 0;

}

void matMult(int A[][5], int B[][5], int C[][5])
{
 int i;
 int j;
 int k;

 for(i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
   for(k = 0; k <= 3; k++) {
    C[i][j] +=  A[i][k] * B[k][j]; 
   }
  }
 }

}

int printMat_5x5(int A[5][5]){

 int i;
 int j;

 for (i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
  for(j = 0;j < 5;j++) {

   printf("%2d",A[i][j]);
  }

  printf("\n");
 }

}
```

EDIT:
Here is the question, sorry for not posting it the first time.

> Write a C function to multiply two five by five matrices. The prototype should read
>
> ```
> void matMult(int a[][5],int b[][5],int c[][5]);
> ```
>
> The resulting matrix product (`a` times `b`) is returned in the two  dimensional array `c`  (the third parameter of the function). Program your solution using three nested for loops (each generating the counter values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4) That is, DO NOT code specific formulas for the 5 by 5 case in the problem, but make your code general so it can be easily changed to compute the product of larger square matrices. Write a main program to test your function using the arrays
>
> ```
> a:
> 1 2 3 4 6
> 6 1 5 3 8
> 2 6 4 9 9
> 1 3 8 3 4
> 5 7 8 2 5
> b:
> 3 5 0 8 7
> 2 2 4 8 3
> 0 2 5 1 2 
> 1 4 0 5 1
> 3 4 8 2 3
> ```
>
> Print your matrices in a neat format using a C function created for printing five by five matrices. Print all three matrices. Generate your test arrays in your main program using the C array initialization feature.

Comment: Do you have an actual question? I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Remember, for a given index `i, j` in the product, you take the `i` th row of the first matrix, `j` th column of the second matrix, and then multiply+add *all* of the `n` pairs of numbers in the two sets.  Why are your index variables going till 2, 4, and 3 respectively?  Where did you get those numbers from?

Comment: I wish I could downvote the professor for wasting their students time, when they could be focusing on something that would actually promote their career after college.

Comment: So, @George, you *have* a Dip.Ed., do you? Or are you just a geek who knows bugger all about the educational process but finds it necessary to comment on it anyway? :-)

Comment: Are you allowed to assume C99 and VLAs?  This cries out to use them.  Note, too, that the question asks you to multiply an NxM matrix by an MxL generating an NxL matrix - if my memory for matrix multiplication is correct. The test is a special case with N = M = L = 5 -- which leaves plenty of room to hide bugs.  What are you supposed to do if the matrices are not multipliable?  Etc.

Answer (score 4):

How come your `printMat_5x5` loops have conditions `i < 5` and `j < 5`, but your `matMult` loops have conditions `i <= 2`, `j <= 4`, and `k <= 3`?

Comment: You might also find it nice to init C to zeros *within* matMult. There's no point forcing another set up step onto the caller (the setting of the target array to all zeros).

Comment: Well, since the function printMat_5x5 only has to print 5x5 matrices and the question states that matMult has to have counter values of 1,2,3,4, and 5.

Comment: @Rick, that phrase calls for counter values of 0,1,2,3,4. What that means is "for (i=0;i<5;i++) ...". In other words *each* counter has to run from 0 through 4 inclusive, not (as you seem to think), one running to 1, another to 2, another to 3 and so on.

Comment: "counter values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4" means your counter goes from 0 to 4, not that you have to have your loop termination conditions set to those numbers.

Comment: If I put all the counters to five my product matrix is still a bunch of random numbers. What else could the problem be?

Comment: I found the problem. Since I was printing the last matrix with a character spacing of 2, I thought the output was gibberish. On further inspection I just needed to space them out father.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 4):

In `matMult()`, all the loop limits should be 5 since you are multiplying 5x5 matrices.  Also, use the idiomatic `for (i = 0; i < dimension; i++)` instead of `for (i = 0; i <= dimension_minus_one; i++)`.

---

The output I get from the program below is:

```
Matrix A:
  1, 2, 3, 4, 6
  6, 1, 5, 3, 8
  2, 6, 4, 9, 9
  1, 3, 8, 3, 4
  5, 7, 8, 2, 5
Matrix B:
  3, 5, 0, 8, 7
  2, 2, 4, 8, 3
  0, 2, 5, 1, 2
  1, 4, 0, 5, 1
  3, 4, 8, 2, 3
Matrix C:
   29,  55,  71,  59,  41
   47,  86,  93,  92,  82
   54, 102, 116, 131,  76
   24,  55,  84,  63,  47
   46,  83, 108, 124,  89
```

The code I used is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int matmul(size_t ax, size_t ay, int a[ax][ay],
                  size_t bx, size_t by, int b[bx][by],
                  size_t cx, size_t cy, int c[cx][cy])
{
    if (ay != bx || ax != cx || by != cy)
        return(-1);  /* Non-compatible matrices */

    size_t i, j, k;

    /* Zero result */
    for (i = 0; i < cx; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < cy; j++)
            c[i][j] = 0;
    }

    /* Compute result - no care about overflows */
    for (i = 0; i < ax; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < by; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < ay; k++)
                c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }
    }

    return(0);
}

static void matminmax(size_t ax, size_t ay, int a[ax][ay],
                      int *pmin, int *pmax)
{
    size_t i, j;
    int max = a[0][0];
    int min = a[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < ax; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < ay; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] > max)
                max = a[i][j];
            else if (a[i][j] < min)
                min = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    *pmin = min;
    *pmax = max;
}

static void set_printformat(const char *pfx, const char *sfx,
                            size_t ax, size_t ay, int a[ax][ay],
                            char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    int min, max;
    matminmax(ax, ay, a, &min, &max);
    int len1 = snprintf(0, 0, "%d", min);
    int len2 = snprintf(0, 0, "%d", max);
    if (len2 > len1)
        len1 = len2;
    snprintf(buffer, buflen, "%s%d%s", pfx, len1, sfx);
}

static void matprt(size_t ax, size_t ay, int a[ax][ay], const char *tag)
{
    size_t i, j;
    char format[32];

    set_printformat("%s%", "d", ax, ay, a, format, sizeof(format));
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    for (i = 0; i < ax; i++)
    {
        const char *pad = "  ";
        for (j = 0; j < ay; j++)
        {
            printf(format, pad, a[i][j]);
            pad = ", ";
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[5][5] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 },
        { 6, 1, 5, 3, 8 },
        { 2, 6, 4, 9, 9 },
        { 1, 3, 8, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 7, 8, 2, 5 },
    };
    int b[5][5] =
    {
        { 3, 5, 0, 8, 7 },
        { 2, 2, 4, 8, 3 },
        { 0, 2, 5, 1, 2 },
        { 1, 4, 0, 5, 1 },
        { 3, 4, 8, 2, 3 },
    };
    int c[5][5];

    matprt(5, 5, a, "Matrix A");
    matprt(5, 5, b, "Matrix B");
    matmul(5, 5, a, 5, 5, b, 5, 5, c);
    matprt(5, 5, c, "Matrix C");
    return(0);
}
```

If anyone would care to explain how to indicate that the two input matrices to `matmul()` are constant and the third is not, I'd appreciate it.

Note that I ignored the possibility of an error return from `matmul()`.